# Unable to get logic correct for registration

Tags: php, html

I made a bunch of if else statements to print out when a user gets through the registration code in php. The code is as follows:

```
<div class="lower-body">
    <div class="left-lower">Create an account</div>
    <div id="account-first">
    <?php 
    /*if(@$_POST['action'] == 'register' && empty($errors) === true){
        echo 'You\'ve been registered successfully!' . "\n"; 
        echo 'Please check email and activate account!'; 
    }else {*/

    if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($totalError) === true ){
        $register_data = array(
            'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
            'lastname'  => $_POST['lastname'],
            'username'  => $_POST['username'],
            'password'  => $_POST['password'],
            'email'     => $_POST['email'],
            'areacode'  => $_POST['areacode']
            );

        register_user($register_data);
        $regDone[] = 'VALUE';
        echo 
        //header('Location: register.php?sucess');
        //exit();
    } else if(empty($errors) === false){
        echo output_errors($errors);
        } else if(empty($regDone) === false){
            echo "Check Email to activate account!";
        }
    //}
?>
```

At the end it says you have to check your email for activation. I added an array and added a value to it after the data is given to mysql. Then I say if it is not empty (should be filled if completed) print the statement.

It makes sense to me but why isnt it working?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We're going to need to see more code...your `else if` isn't closed, where does `$errors` come from, etc...and what @CaptOtis said.

Comment: That was for the commented if else above. It doesnt go with anything

Comment: My if else is commented out

Comment: "$regDone[] = 'VALUE';
        echo ",Do you know the syntax of echo?Remove echo without ending ;

Comment: I did not see that echo that was from a test. Thank you for spotting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not getting you wrong you need to use `if` instead `else if`.

```
if(empty($regDone) === false){
    echo "Check Email to activate account!";
}
```